# Remoting Through an Array of Webservers to Deploy Code

Tags: powershell, iis, remote-server, iis-10

I'm looking to pop through a few webservers and import-module WebAdministration in order to change some recycling properties.

The issue is, it seems like foreach doesn't like being used for remote sessions. I'm guessing this is because a single block of code can only be executed in 1 remote session? Is there a way to pop through multiple sessions or do I have to do that by hand?

Just looking for some input on how to write a code to deploy to all my apppools on all my servers.

I've tested wildcarding the appPool directory and that seems to work.

IIS10
Powershell 5.1.14393.2189

```
$servers = @("MyEnvironment-web01","MyEnvironment-web02","MyEnvironment-web03")
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    enter-Pssession -ComputerName $server
    Write-Host $server
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue" #This was added because I thought maybe it just needed time to connect? Doesn't need to be in here.
    import-module WebAdministration
        Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\*
        exit-PSSession
        }
```

Lots of this: 
import-module : The specified module 'WebAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1

Which is odd because that works just fine if I run the for-each loop manually. Except about 20% of the time when it doesn't....

I'm willing to bet I'm going about this ALL wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829087/unable-to-fetch-application-pools-from-list-of-remote-servers-looping-isnt-work). In short: You should create a new-pssession and use the session with invoke-command.

Comment: I really looked for something but I couldn't find it!

That being said, yup! that's what I needed. Answer credit for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Cred = Get-Credential -UserName <domain\user> -Message 'Enter Password'
$servers = @("myserver1"."myserver2","etc")
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred {
    import-module WebAdministration
    Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\*
    }
}
```